# Symmetric matrix over inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

I try really hard to prove this Question.
let $A_{nXn}(\mathbb{R})$ Symmetric  matrix $A=A^t$
let $\lambda$ be the greatest Eigenvalue of A. 
we will define over the field $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard inner product a Linear map such that

$\forall v \in R^n$,   $v \to Av$

prove : 
$$\max_{\displaystyle{\forall v\in R^n}\atop{\displaystyle ||v||=1}}  < Av,v >=\lambda$$

Comment: You can use that the matrix is diagonalizable with on orthonormal basis of eigenvectors

Comment: i already tried it, doesn't help for me ..

Comment: You might try using the $\LaTeX$ "\to" for "|->", thusly:  $\to$; I took the liberty of editing it into your question; if you don't find my edit helpful, feel free to change it back.  Cheers!

Comment: $Hint_1$: Did you try use Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality?

Comment: $Hint_2$: If $\lambda$ is a eigeinvalue of $v$, then $\frac{v}{|v|}$ has the same eigeinvalue.

Comment: $Hint_3$: Can you prove that there exists any $w$ such that $\langle Aw,w\rangle=\lambda$?

Comment: This is not true, sir. In the statement, $|\lambda|$ on the right-hand side should be replaced by the *maximal* eigenvalue of $A$ unless you want to take a maximum of *absolute values* of $\langle Ax,x\rangle$ on the left-hand side.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel The statement in the original question is correct, but someone had edited the question wrongly. I have just rolled back the question to a previous version.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks. I didn't notice before that there were so many "improvements". I'd call it rather a vandalism :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symmetric matrices over ${\mathbb{R}}$ are diagonalizable; choose an orthonormal basis $x_1, \dots, x_n$ of eigenvectors of $A$ belonging to eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$. (That is, $\left<x_i, x_j\right> = 0$ for $i\not = j$; each $\left<x_i, x_i\right> = 1$; and $Ax_i = \lambda_i x_i$.) Then for $x = t_1 x_1 + \cdots + t_n x_n$, we have
$$\left<Ax, x\right> = \sum t_i t_j \left<Ax_i, x_j\right> = t_1^2 \lambda_1 + \cdots + t_n^2 \lambda_n \leq (t_1^2 + \cdots + t_n^2)\lambda = \lambda\left<x, x\right>$$
(provided $\lambda \geq 0)$.
The result follows.

Comment: why does $(t_1^2 + \cdots + t_n^2)=<x,x>$ ?

Comment: I suppose that he has considered the vector unitary

Comment: The $x_i$ are orthonormal. (I'm also assuming we're in a real vector space; otherwise, put in conjugates as appropriate.)

Comment: Also, as mentioned above, you need $\lambda \geq 0$ (or some similar assumption). For example, if $A = -1$, then the inner product $\left<Ax, x\right> = -1$ for $|x| = 1$. You might have dropped an absolute value sign on the left side of the equation in the OP; that would make it the operator norm.